# While loop in layout activity_main. New to Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, layout, while-loop

It's a simple idea. Not sure if I can do it in activity_main. In my layout I want to have it create table rows based on X. Still need to implement X. But for now I am not sure if it can be done.

```
  
  
     // Where I try to create a while loop to loop the table row based on x.
        var i = 0
        var x = 3
    
        while (i > x) {
        println(i)
    
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff">
          
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text=" order " />
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="Del Note "
                />
    
         
        </TableRow>

    
        i++
        }

    
    </TableLayout>
```

Alright So I know now I am wrong and this is not how it should be done. Can I please be directed into a manner in which this can be done.

Comment: You can’t put code in an XML file and you can’t put and XML resource in your code. You can do this sort of thing in Compose.

Comment: without trying to sound rude, you need to review the basics, that's not how this works :)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I was literally thrown into this with a short expected delivery date. So I did not really have time to learn first and thought I would learn as I go.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thank you for the recommendation. I will go and learn what Compose is.

Comment: you're going to waste a lot more time by trying out random stuff and expecting it to work, instead of just taking some time to review the basics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML is only to be used for resources such as layouts, animations, vector images, and so forth. Kotlin cannot be directly implemented into an XML file, which is why every activity generates a Kotlin code file and a corresponding XML file.

What it looks like you are trying to do is display the same thing three times. For this you would need to use a Recycler View and use Kotlin to control what it does. You can read up on what a Recycler View on the [Google Developer Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) is and how to do this. Just a side note, at a beginner level a Recycler View can be very confusing just starting out.